# How to create a trigger for the table already being used

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER abc
after insert ON visadetails
FOR EACH ROW update visadetails SET VisaId=concat(new.Occupation,'-',new.Vid);

insert into visadetails (Occupation,Destination) value("student","rome");
```

after creating trigger m not able to insert the value, it gives following error message

> #1442 - Can't update table 'gallery' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: What do you expect. Your trigger will trigger this trigger ...

Answer (score 0):

No need for an update (which btw would have updated *all* rows in the table with the result of the `concat()` for the new row because of the missing `where` clause).

```
CREATE TRIGGER abc
after insert ON visadetails
FOR EACH ROW 
   SET new.VisaId=concat(new.Occupation,'-',new.Vid);
```